# there is an error When switching between documents' tab in Spago BI reports

Tags: spagobi

In Spago BI , I have created some documents in a folder.
when I run more than one document (report) together in the folder, for every documents(reports) is opened one tab (It's normal). But when I switch from one tab to another one in order to see documents' (reports) detail, I see this message "An error has occurred. Retry later.
If the problems persists, contact the system administrator."
this error appears only for documents that include charts. namely, instead of every charts which are in the (document) report, the error is appeared.

Are there any solution to solve this problem???